# MySql Calculations

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to add columns in MySQL and dynamically populate another columns.

e.g 
i have a table 'numbers'
and have column 1, column 2, column 3 and the total of these should be populated in column 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, aren't you just looking for:

```
UPDATE numbers SET column4 = (column1 + column2 + column3);
```

That will update `column4` in all rows of the table *numbers* to be the sum of the first 3 columns.

Alternatively, you could also do the addition during `SELECT`:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, (column1 + column2 + column3) AS column4 FROM numbers;
```

in which case you wouldn't need an actual column4 in the database table.

**Edit:**
To make it update column4 every time one of the other columns was updated you could use a trigger: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html (There's actually an example of something very similar in the linked docs.)

Use triggers with caution though, not because there's anything inherently wrong with them — not at all — but because using them sometimes moves logic that belongs in code into a place where it can be difficult to locate, debug and keep in version control.

Comment: thanks you Madsen ,and what if i wanted it to update column4 every time the different values were updated?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select field_1, field_2, field_3, (field_1+field_2+field_3) as field_4 from your_table
```

Comment: Hey Thiago if you dont mind me asking, but may you please explain how this line would work.

Comment: the first 3 fields are the columns from your table, the 4th one is a simple arithmatic... it will select values from fields 1,2 and 3 and sum it.I  defined its result as "field_4" but it could be any name you want, this way you can do your calculations in a single query i hope it has became clearer now :) fell free to ask if you want

Comment: so this wont permanently store the value it will just use the field_4 to temporarily display the calculations, is that right?

Comment: Ah okay, it wasn't what i was originally looking for but that works great for the next thing i had to do, Thank you very much for the help Thiago.